# How to make JButton Uneditable

Tags: java

i am creating a Tic tac toe project with the simple JButtons i have set the images for 0 and * in JButton but i want that JButton Should not be change if they are clicked once so that when 1 user will press on a button then the image on the JButton should not be changed

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class My
{
public static Boolean flag=true;
}
class Tic extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JButton btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9;
ImageIcon img,img1;
Tic()
{
    img=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Love\\Desktop\\z.jpeg");
    img1=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Love\\Desktop\\k.jpeg");
    btn1=new JButton();btn2=new JButton();btn3=new JButton();
    btn4=new JButton();btn5=new JButton();btn6=new JButton();
    btn7=new JButton();btn8=new JButton();btn9=new JButton();
    btn1.setBounds(0,0,80,70);btn2.setBounds(80,0,80,70);btn3.setBounds(160,0,80,70);
    btn4.setBounds(0,70,80,70);btn5.setBounds(80,70,80,70);btn6.setBounds(160,70,80,70);
    btn7.setBounds(0,140,80,70);btn8.setBounds(80,140,80,70);btn9.setBounds(160,140,80,70);
    btn1.addActionListener(this);btn2.addActionListener(this);btn3.addActionListener(this);
    btn4.addActionListener(this);btn5.addActionListener(this);btn6.addActionListener(this);
    btn7.addActionListener(this);btn8.addActionListener(this);btn9.addActionListener(this);
    add(btn1);add(btn2);add(btn3);
    add(btn4);add(btn5);add(btn6);
    add(btn7);add(btn8);add(btn9);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(246,240);
    setLocation(400,200);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    JButton temp=(JButton)e.getSource();//System.out.println(temp);
    if(temp==btn1||temp==btn2||temp==btn3||temp==btn4||temp==btn5||temp==btn6||temp==btn7||temp==btn8||temp==btn9){
    if(My.flag==true)
    {
        temp.setIcon(img1);temp.setEnabled(false);
        //temp.setText("<html><font color=red></font></html>");
        My.flag=false;
    }
    else
    {
        temp.setIcon(img);
        temp.setEnabled(false);
        My.flag=true;
    }
    // btn1 btn2 btn3
    //btn
}
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    new Tic().setTitle("Tic_Tac_Toe..Love--Soni");
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add the code to explain more clearly what you have done, the question is very vague to answer.

Comment: i just want that the if the button is pressed again then the image of the button should not be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your buttons are starting with no text in them, and changing by firing an `ActionListener`. If that is the case, then before you change the text in the `JButton`, just check to see if the text it currently holds is an empty `String`. If it is empty, make the changes. If it isn't empty, do nothing.

So your `ActionListener` should look something like this:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
        if(b.getText().equals("")){
            //Logic to determine what it should be set to...
            b.setText("0"); // or "*"
        }
    }
});
```

You could also disable the buttons after they have changed, which would look like this:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
        //Logic to determine what it should be set to...
        b.setText("0"); // or "*"
        b.setEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

***UPDATE SINCE CODE ADDED***

You should just have to update your if condition to this:

```
if((temp==btn1||temp==btn2||temp==btn3||temp==btn4||temp==btn5||temp==btn6||temp==btn7||temp==btn8||temp==btn9) 
                    && temp.getText().equals("")) {
```

Comment: but it is still changing and if i will use setEnabled(false) button becomes dull in color

Comment: Can i change the color of the button after disable it

Comment: I'm confused by your first comment. I just ran your code and when a button is pressed, it becomes disabled and is no longer capable of being pressed. So it seems to work how you want it to. As for the color of the button - yes you can change that even if the button is disabled. After `temp.setEnabled(false);` you can put this line: `temp.setBackground(Color.RED);`. It doesn't have to be `Color.RED` by the way, that's just an example.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark my answer as correct so that your question no longer appears unanswered.

Comment: I am using the picture over the button as i use the setBackground method only the backgound color get change 
     I just want that the image on the button should not be changed if someone presses the button 2 time and its color should also be same that is not happpens when i use  setEnabled(false) method